# tap.throws() doesn't work when called with prototypically inherited function?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, prototypal-inheritance

I'm using constructor functions with prototypical inheritance to build a small library. I'm trying to test that one of the methods throws an error.

Sample code:

```
function Thing() {
    this.x = 'ok'
}

Thing.prototype.trySomething = function() {
    throw new Error('test error')
}

const thing = new Thing()
tap.throws(function() { throw new Error('before')}) // this is fine
tap.throws(thing.trySomething()) // urgh
tap.throws(function() { throw new Error('after')}) // never runs
```

Looks like tap is just throwing the error from `trySomething`. Running the tests gives me the following results:

```
ok 1 - expected to throw
not ok 2 - test error
```

And test 3 doesn't run.

I'm using node-tap (https://github.com/tapjs/node-tap).

> t.throws(fn, [expectedError], message, extra)
>
> Expect the function to throw an error. If an expected error is provided, then also verify that the thrown error matches the expected error.

but the same thing seems to happen with native `assert`.

Any idea what is going on here and how to write a passing test?

Comment: In your second example you are not passing a function you are passing the *result* of a function. Try passing in the function without calling it (without the `()`)

Comment: yup, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

The `tap.throws` assert function accepts a `fn`/`function`

Just do this

```
tap.throws(thing.trySomething, {})
```

remove the `()`, it will work fine